# Imagine library images has black background, set it to white

Tags: image

Imagine images has black background when created, how do I fix it?

```
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
```

Setting it to white makes it delete white designs in png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$backgroundColor = new ImagickPixel('None'); 
$im->setImageBackgroundColor($backgroundColor);
```

Set color to none. It should fix this issue.